# Открывается два виджета одновременно

Tags: c++, qt, виджет

У меня есть 4 виджета : startWidget, mainWidget, student widget, teacherWidget. 
В startWidget я выбираю который открыть student widget или teacherWidget и на заднем фоне у меня открыт mainWidget. Как сделать чтобы student widget, teacherWidget открывалися в mainWidget а не в другом окне?

```
 #include "StudyTests.h"
 #include "MainWidget.h"
 #include "StudentWidget.h"
 #include "TeacherWidget.h"
 #include "StartProgramMenuWidget.h"
 #include "HelpWidget.h"

int StudyTests::runGame()
{
   mMainWidget = new MainWidget();
   mMainWidget->show();

   StartProgramMenuWidget startProgramMenu;

   connect(&startProgramMenu, SIGNAL(startProgramStudent()), this, 
   SLOT(startProgramStudent()));
   connect(&startProgramMenu, SIGNAL(startProgramTeacher()), this, 
   SLOT(startProgramTeacher()));
   connect(&startProgramMenu, SIGNAL(exitProgram()), this, 
   SLOT(exitProgram()));
   connect(&startProgramMenu, SIGNAL(showHelp()), this, SLOT(showHelp()));
   startProgramMenu.exec();

  return 0;
}

void StudyTests::startProgramStudent()
{
   mStudentWidget = new StudentWidget();
   mStudentWidget->show();
   mMainWidget->close();

}
void StudyTests::startProgramTeacher()
{
  mTeacherWidget = new TeacherWidget();
  mTeacherWidget->show();
  mMainWidget->close();
}

void StudyTests::exitProgram()
{
  mMainWidget->close();
}

void StudyTests::showHelp()
{
  HelpWidget helpWidget;
  helpWidget.exec();
}

StudyTests::~StudyTests()
{
  delete mMainWidget;
  delete mStudentWidget;
  delete mTeacherWidget;
}
```

mainWidget

```
  #include "MainWidget.h"
  #include "StudentWidget.h"
  #include "TeacherWidget.h"

MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget* parent)
: QWidget(parent)
{
  setWindowTitle("Тести");
  setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
}

MainWidget::~MainWidget()
{
}
```

UPD:

```
void MainWidget::setStudent()
{
   mStudentWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, 
   QSizePolicy::Expanding);
   mStudentWidget->setParent(this);
   QVBoxLayout* vLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
   vLayout->addWidget(mStudentWidget);

   setLayout(vLayout);
}
void MainWidget::setTeacher()
{
  mTeacherWidget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, 
   QSizePolicy::Expanding);
  mTeacherWidget->setParent(this);
  QVBoxLayout* vLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
   vLayout->addWidget(mTeacherWidget);

   setLayout(vLayout);
}
```

Comment: а от чего пронаследованы классы mStudentWidget/mTeacherWidget ?

Comment: @goldstar_labs public QWidget

Comment: Выглядит корректно, попробуйте при создании виджетов mStudentWidget явно указать родителя, т.е. mStudentWidget = new StudentWidget(mMainWidget);

Comment: @goldstar_labs                             
                      MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget* parent)
                      : QWidget(parent)
                      , mStudentWidget (new StudentWidget(this))
                      , mTeacherWidget(new TeacherWidget(this))
                        {     я  так созда. не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Используй

```
QWidget::setParent()
```

или

```
QLayout::addWidget()
```

Также, когда динамически создаешь виджет можешь сразу указывать родителя (По умолчанию там либо 0 либо nullptr). Например:

```
mStudentWidget = new StudentWidget(ptr) //ptr - указатель на твое главное окно
```

Comment: я переделал, но не работает. Смотреть UPD

Comment: setLayout() применяется только к объектам QWidget. Если ты делал в дизайнере и главное окно является наследником QMainWindow, то попробуй ui->centralWidget->setLayout(vLayout). Вообще, если все-таки работаешь с дизайнером, то ты можешь прямо в самом дизайнере добавить на свое окно объект QWidget->правой кнопкой мыши по нему->преобразовать в->вводишь имя своего виджета и путь к его хедеру->преобразовать. И ты получишь прямо в дизайнере свой пользовательский виджет.

Comment: нет я не  делал в  дезайнере